# create seperate instances in each element in list/dict comprehension in Python

Tags: python, django, dictionary, functional-programming, list-comprehension

My codes are like this:

```
widgets = {x: Select2Widget(attrs={"style": "width: 300px;"}) for x in
               ['paper', 'factor', 'cell_line', 'cell_type']}
```

This will cause error because all the values of the dict of `widgets` will share the same instance. To avoid this issue, I'll have to write the codes like the following:

```
    widgets = {
        'paper': Select2Widget(attrs={"style" : "width: 300px;"}),
        'factor': Select2Widget(attrs={"style" : "width: 300px;"}),
        'cell_line': Select2Widget(attrs={"style" : "width: 300px;"}),
        'cell_type': Select2Widget(attrs={"style" : "width: 300px;"}),}
```

I was wondering whether this is a way to write concise codes while assigning different instance for the value of each element in the dictionary. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using a dict comprehension creates **separate instances**.

That is the *point* of a dict comprehension; the left-hand side expressions for key and value are evaluated *each iteration*.

Demo:

```
>>> demo = {i: [] for i in range(3)}
>>> demo[0] is demo[1]
False
```

Here separate lists are created. If you were to use, say, `dict.fromkeys()` then you would be sharing the same value:

```
>>> demo = dict.fromkeys(range(3), [])
>>> demo[0] is demo[1]
True
```

Because your dict comprehension uses a literal dict expression for the `attrs` keyword, the dict you pass to the `Select2Widget()` instance is unique and not shared between values in the resulting dictionary.

Just stick to your dict comprehension, it is working just fine.